# Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system

Tags: gpu, nvidia, podman

I'm working on a RedHat 9.1 system and trying to enable GPU access to podman.  (I actually want to run Docker with GPU access, but apparently that isn't supported on RedHat 9.1.)

I followed [these instructions](https://egallen.com/rhel8-podman-gpu/) and initially received an "insufficient permissions" error when I tried to run the example container, which simply runs `nvidia-smi`.   (When I run `nvidia-smi` from the host, I get the expected output, and I'm able to run GPU-dependent jobs from the host.  At least the drivers and libraries appear to be correctly installed for the host.)

[This issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1608) and various others describes a fix for that problem in which `/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml` is adjusted such that `#no-cgroups = false` is changed to `no-cgroups = true`.  This removes the insufficient permissions problem, but then I get the GPU-access blocked error.

I found a number of other posts that gave a different fix for the first error in which `#user = "root:root"` in the config.toml is uncommented and changed to match the ownership of `/dev/nvidia*` - all of those are `root:root` on this system and making that change in config.toml did not help.

I found a few suggestions for the blocked by OS error, but they consisted of the same sets of changes to config.toml.  Also, I have restarted the podman service after changing config.toml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an SELinux file context issue.

You can see the file contexts by running `ls -lZ /dev | grep nvidia`

Running

`chcon -t container_file_t /dev/nvidia*`

changes the file context of the nvidia devices such that containers are allowed to access them.  I also had to include the specific devices on the command line when running `podman`

`sudo podman run --gpus all --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidia1:/dev/nvidia1 --device /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvidiactl --rm nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-runtime-ubi8 nvidia-smi`

This works, and it fixes the problem for Docker as well.

Note that the `chcon -t container_file_t /dev/nvidia*` is temporary and file contexts will revert back when the system is rebooted.  To make the changes permanent, run

`semanage fcontext -a -t container_file_t '/dev/nvidia*'`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd like to see this added to the Nvidia container-toolkit package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yes, it would have been nice had this be documented. I thought having it here would at least be useful. I'm glad you found it so.  8^D